# Як правильно вживати слова "воєнний", "військовий" та "воїнський"?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, вибір-слова

Неодноразово помічав різноманітний стиль вживання слів *воєнний* та *військовий* (і трошки рідше — *воїнський*).

> *У Ханої пройшов **воєнний** парад з нагоди 70-річчя незалежності країни* — [ICTV](http://fakty.ictv.ua/ua/videos/100756/)
>
> ***Військовий** парад у Львові […] колона із 17 парадних розрахунків **військових** частин […] у параді задіяли більш як півсотні **військової** техніки* — [5 канал](http://www.5.ua/suspilstvo/viiskovyi-parad-u-lvovi-na-marsh-zakhysnykiv-pryishly-podyvytysia-kilka-tysiach-mistian-132958.html)

**Яке правило регламентує правильне вживання цих трьох слів?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ключовим правилом є звертання уваги на корені наведених слів:

- Якщо слово стосується **війни**, то [**воєнний**](http://sum.in.ua/s/vojennyj) (походить від слова *війна*)
- Якщо слово стосується **армії, війська**, то [**військовий**](http://sum.in.ua/s/vijsjkovyj) (походить від слова *військо*).
  Мнемоніка — можна замінити на слово *«армійський»*.
- Якщо слово стосується **особи** бійця, то [**воїнський**](http://sum.in.ua/s/vojinsjkyj) (походить від слова *воїн*).
  Мнемоніка — можна замінити на слово *«солдатський»*.

---

Приклади:

> **Воєнний** — стан, план, інтереси, конфлікт, злочин, суд, трибунал, доктрина, загроза;
>
> **Військовий** — бюджет, госпіталь, кореспондент, частина, служба, техніка, форма, справа, таємниця, оркестр, парад;
>
> **Воїнський** — героїзм, честь, слава, обов’язок, доблесть;

Деякі джерела [вказують](http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53394/30344.html), що з деякими словами допустиме паралельне вживання *військовий* і *воєнний* — блок, союз, суд, трибунал, наука, промисловість, стратегія, тактика, теорія, зіткнення, потреби тощо.

А СУМ взагалі вказує на два рівноправні значення слова [*військовий*](http://sum.in.ua/s/vijsjkovyj), посилаючись на численні приклади з літератури.

Моя особиста думка — що неточності з'явилися внаслідок впливу російської мови, де слово <sub>рос.</sub>*«войсковой»* доволі обмежене в ужитку, а натомість слово <sub>рос.</sub>*«военный»* несе обидва значення.