# Транспортна чи транспортова

Tags: прикметники

Помітив, що в міжмережжі часто вживають слово *транспортова*, але я звик чути *транспортна*, наприклад [транспортна система](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0). Як правильно?

> Ціла низка суфіксів другої групи виступає в якісних та відносно-якісних прикметниках у поєднанні з основами іменників та дієслів: *-на-, -лив-, **-н-*** на означення якостей і властивостей людини (*правдивий, хворобливий, сонний*); …

> Суфікс ***-н-***, поєднуючись з основами іменників, що є назвами будівлі, її частини, територіальних установ, виражає ознаки предметів за просторовими відношеннями (*стінний годинник, районний відділ*), за призначенням (*віконна рама, хатнє збіжжя, машинний завод*). У поєднанні з основами іменників, що позначають пори року, дня, відлік *часу*, суфікс ***-н-*** передає ознаку за часом: *річний, столітній, денний, осінній, жнивний.*

Як можна побачити варіант *транспортний* підходить під ознаку предметів за призначенням, бо для транспорту.

> Найбільш уживані суфікси відносних прикметників ***-н-**, -ан-(-ян-), **-ов-**, -ев-(-єв-)* виступають на означення матеріалу, з якого зроблено предмет: *мідний, гречаний, пшоняний, березовий, смушевий, баєвий.*

> Суфікс *-ів-* у формах прикметників жіночого й середнього роду однини та в множині виступає в різних фонетичних варіантах: ***-ов(а)**, -ов(е), -ов(і)* - у прикметниках, утворених від іменників другої відміни твердої групи (*брат - братів - братова - братове - братові; Петро - Петрів - Петрова - Петрове - Петрові); -ев(а), -ев(е), -ев(і)* - у прикметниках, утворених від іменників другої відміни м'якої і мішаної груп (*коваль—ковалів—ковалева - ковалеве—ковалеві; Ігор - Ігорів - Ігорева -Ігореве - Ігореві; товариш — товаришів — товаришева - товаришеве - товаришеві*).

> Від назв тварин та інших істот творяться присвійні прикметники за допомогою суфіксів -*ач-(-яч-), -ій, -ин-(-їн-), **-ов-**, -ев-* або нульового суфікса: *котячий, козячий, орлій, журавлиний, зміїний, тигровий, коневий (і конячий), ведмежий.*

Здавалось би, що для *-ов-* місця нема, але ось є примітка, в якій зустрічається слово *крановий*, то може й *транспортовий* можна?

> Примітка. Суфікс ***-ов-*** приєднується до основ іменників першої і другої відмін твердої групи (*кран - крановий, липа - липовий, діло - діловий*) та м'якої і мішаної, якщо наголос у прикметнику падає на закінчення (*плащ - плащовий, руль - рульовий*). Суфікс *-ев-(-ев-)* виступає після основ іменників першої і другої відмін м'якої і мішаної груп, якщо наголос в утвореному прикметнику падає на корінь або на суфікс (*соя - соєвий, мить -миттєвий, спориш - споришевий, життя - життєвий і життьовий*).

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту і вітаємо вас з чудовим першим запитанням!

Answer (score 1):

Імовірно, **транспортовий** є застарілою формою **транспортний**, та майже не використовується в наш час
Але якщо розглядати **транспортовий** як окреме значення то підійде аналогія  з [**воєнний/військовий**](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/640/4672)

- **Транспортний** - стосується транспортування взагалі
- **Транспортовий** - стосується засобів та субʼєктів транспортування, інфраструктури, тощо